# BST implementation

Tags: c, implementation, binary-search-tree

What's wrong with the following implementation of a [binary search tree (BST)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)? I have been told that it is better to use pointer to a pointer to `struct` node as an argument in insert function.

```
struct node
{
int key_value;
struct node* left;
struct node* right;
};

insert(int key, struct node *leaf)
{
    if( leaf == 0 )
    {
        leaf = (struct node*) malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
        leaf->key_value = key;
        /* initialize the children to null */
        leaf->left = 0;    
        leaf->right = 0;  
    }
    else if(key < leaf->key_value)
    {
        insert( key, leaf->left );
    }
    else if(key > leaf->key_value)
    {
        insert( key, leaf->right );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
leaf = (struct node*) malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
```

gives a new value to `leaf`, pointing it at some newly allocated memory.  However, the new value does not leave the function.  When the function returns, the caller will still be referring to the old `leaf`, and there will be a memory leak.

There are two approaches you could take to fixing it:

**1.** Use a pointer to a pointer, e.g.

```
void insert(int key, struct node **leaf)
{
    if(*leaf == 0 )
    {
        *leaf = (struct node*) malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
        ...
}

/* In caller -- & is prepended to current_leaf. */
insert(37, &current_leaf);
```

**2.** Return the new leaf (or the old leaf if there is no change).

```
struct node *insert(int key, struct node *leaf)
{
    if(leaf == 0 )
    {
        leaf = (struct node*) malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
        ...
    }

    return leaf;
}

/* In caller -- & is prepended to current_leaf. */
current_leaf = insert(37, current_leaf);
```

Pointers to pointers are close to the threshold of being hard to comprehend.  I would probably go for the second option, if `insert` isn't currently returning anything else.

Answer (score 1):

When a node is inserted (leaf == 0), you didn't change its parent, so the new node will become an orphan.

In other words, your tree will still look like only one node, no matter how many nodes were called with insert.

Answer (score -2):

```
  #include<stdio.h>
     typedef struct tnode{
       int data;
       struct tnode *left,*right;
     }TNODE;
     TNODE * createTNode(int key){
       TNODE *nnode;
       nnode=(TNODE *)malloc(sizeof(TNODE));    
       nnode->data=key;
       nnode->left=NULL;
       nnode->right=NULL;
      return nnode;
}

    TNODE * insertBST(TNODE *root,int key){
     TNODE *nnode,*parent,*temp;
     temp=root;
      while(temp){
        parent=temp;
        if(temp->data > key)
            temp=temp->left;
        else
            temp=temp->right;    
    }    
     nnode=createTNode(key);
    if(root==NULL)
        root=nnode;
    else if(parent->data>key)
        parent->left=nnode;
    else
        parent->right=nnode;
    return root;
}

     void preorder(TNODE *root){
       if(root){
         printf("%5d",root->data);    
         preorder(root->left);
         preorder(root->right);
       }    
     }  

    void inorder(TNODE *root){
       if(root){
        inorder(root->left);
        printf("%5d",root->data);    
        inorder(root->right);
      }    
    }

    void postorder(TNODE *root){
       if(root){
        postorder(root->left);    
        postorder(root->right);
        printf("%5d",root->data);
      }    
    }

     main(){
       TNODE *root=NULL;
       int ch,key;
       do{
         printf("\n\n1-Insert\t2-Preorder\n3-Inorder\t4-Postorder\n5-Exit\n");
         printf("Enter Your Choice: ");
         scanf("%d",&ch);  

        switch(ch){ 
            case 1:
                printf("Enter Element: ");
                scanf("%d",&key);
                root=insertBST(root,key);
                break;
            case 2:
                preorder(root);
                break;
            case 3:
                inorder(root);
                break;
            case 4:
                postorder(root);
                break;
            default:
                printf("\nWrong Choice!!");
        }

    }while(ch!=5);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a short description of what you're doing?